# how to pass the arguments to the function given below, I am using a DS applied on case class. apparently the function is expecting seq[case class]

Tags: scala, function, dataset

[image]
AddressRawData and AddressData both are case class
I am getting data in the addressDF

[image]

Now I have to parse the data to the function addressParser, Unfortunately the parser is expecting Seq[AddressData] and returning Seq[AddressData]
Keeping the function "addressParser" untouched how do I pass my addressDS to  the function "addressParser" ?
[image]

[image]

I have attached my code on the below url
git@github.com:chameleonlabs2021/assessment.git

Comment: Hi, I didn't quite understand your question, since there are some few things you need to do to make your question more readable and understandable. First thing is to provide some sample data from your csv file, just a line or two would be enough. Second thing is to always provide some information about the exception, like providing stacktrace or something. Third thing is to use the actual code and not some pictures, the code is always easier to keep track of. I'll provide some code-related stuff in the next comment.

Comment: One thing is to not to use null, specially when your fields are optional, you can use None in this case. When using functions in order to do something for all elements of a collection, it's better to define a function which accepts a **single** element and returns a **single** result, then you can use map, flatMap, filter and etc with that function, so instead of `def fn(elems: Seq[A]): Seq[B]`, use `def fn(elem: A): B`, I'll also take a look again on your question as you update it!

Comment: please don't use screancast

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) --> "Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted into an editor and compiled in order to reproduce the problem."

Comment: Post code as text, NOT IMAGES.

Comment: @AminMal I tried so many times to give my code, However, stackoverflow it is repeatedly prompting to correct indentation which I fixed still it is not allowing me to submit code. Eventually I have no other option other than uploading the code image.I have attached my code on github git@github.com:chameleonlabs2021/assessment.git

Comment: sorry everyone stackoverflow was not allowing me to upload code.  Please find the code in the github git@github.com:chameleonlabs2021/assessment.git

Comment: Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon. so annoying...stackoverflow